# dict_keys object does not support indexing

Tags: python, typeerror

I have no idea what is the problem here:

```
net.blobs['data'].reshape(*(1, 3, imageToTest_padded.shape[0], imageToTest_padded.shape[1]))
#net.forward() # dry run
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = np.transpose(np.float32(imageToTest_padded[:,:,:,np.newaxis]), (3,2,0,1))/256 - 0.5;
start_time = time.time()
output_blobs = net.forward()
print('At scale %d, The CNN took %.2f ms.' % (m, 1000 * (time.time() - start_time)))

# extract outputs, resize, and remove padding
heatmap = np.transpose(np.squeeze(net.blobs[output_blobs.keys()[1]].data), (1,2,0))  # output 1 is heatmaps
heatmap = cv.resize(heatmap, (0,0), fx=model['stride'], fy=model['stride'], interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
heatmap = heatmap[:imageToTest_padded.shape[0]-pad[2], :imageToTest_padded.shape[1]-pad[3], :]
heatmap = cv.resize(heatmap, (oriImg.shape[1], oriImg.shape[0]), interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
```

Getting an error TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing in line

```
heatmap = np.transpose(np.squeeze(net.blobs[output_blobs.keys()[1]].data), (1,2,0))  # output 1 is heatmaps
```

Original code: https://github.com/ZheC/Realtime_Multi-Person_Pose_Estimation

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the original code came from the old python 2 when `dict.keys()` returned a list.  Try `list(output_blobs.keys())[1]` for python 3 (untested).

Answer (score 0):

You could try looping through the keys of the dictionary:

```
for key in output_blobs.keys():
    heatmap = np.transpose(np.squeeze(net.blobs[output_blobs[key].data), (1,2,0))
```

I cannot test that this will work for you though, and there may be a better way than looping available.

Comment: This will loop through all the keys though, so if there are keys you want to skip you would have to specify them with logic using this method...